# Trying to install regular expressions for Python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, module

I'm still new to installing modules on my computer with windows and python 3.3. I'm trying to install the regular expressions module. I have pip installed on my computer, so I tried "pip install regex" but that created a folder called "pip" in my user folder and there is a text file called "pip". It did not put any files in the site-packages folder like the openpyxl and xlsxwriter modules I already have. I am also having this issue with the urllib module.

Comment: Python already comes with both the builtin [`re`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module for regular expressions, and the [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) package. There is no need to further install anything.

Comment: Well that shows how much I know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @poke: You could post this as an answer, so it's clear that the problem is solved. According to [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer) it would be a "valid" answer.

Comment: @IchUndNichtDu Good point, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python already by default comes with a large number of builtin modules. These modules are called the “standard library” and are [well documented](http://docs.python.org/3/library/).

In your case, if you want to use regular expressions, you can use the standard [`re`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. The [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) package is also part of the standard library and offers different modules to perform for example HTTP requests or URL parsing.